# What could cause SharePoint to be unable to download a WSDL?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, download, bdc

I created a BDC entry using the editor delivered with the SharePoint 2007 SDK. On my local installation there is no problem. When the sysadmin tries to import it into the staging farm, he gets the following error message:

> Application definition import failed.
>   The following error occurred: There
>   was an error downloading
>   'http://path/to/someservice?WSDL=1'..
>   Error was encountered at or just
>   before Line: 0 and Position: 0

The path is accessible to anyone within the organization. The WSDL has been verified to be valid. I also tried putting the WSDL in a physical file and pointing to that file in the BDC entry, but still no luck.

Additional question: does SharePoint need execute rights to process the BDC entry?

Answer (score 0):

The webservice is hosted in the Sharepoint server?

Also take in mind that to import a BDC definition the logged user needs Edit right in the **Business Data Catalog Permissions** section, inside the SSP where you are uploading the file.

Regards.